# Creating password protected zip file in R

Tags: r, zip

I have tried following code to generate a password protected zip file in R, but it didn't work and didn't give any error either.

```
zip('file.zip', 
files = 'file.pdf',
flags = paste("--password", 'pwd123'))
```

Can anyone say what's wrong in this code or how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were close, but need to add your commands to the `extras` argument as a list:

```
pdf("file.pdf")
  plot(1)
dev.off()

zip('file.zip', 
  files = 'file.pdf',
  extras = list(paste("--password", 'pwd123'))
)
```

Comment: pdf("file.pdf")
  plot(1)
dev.off() what are theh for?

Comment: I made a pdf first, since what you are zipping was not in your example. The second part is what you are interested in I believe. Works for me. You must have already created a file named "file.pdf" in order for the function to know what should be zipped.

Comment: btw - On my computer, I am only asked for the password during the initial opening of the file. Perhaps this is reset after an elapsed amount of time.

Comment: did't work for me